# jacocoTestCoverageVerification for module level not for each package

Tags: gradle, jacoco

jacocoTestCoverageVerification runs for each package in the project. i want run against the module level. is there any way i can run rule for each module?

```
    violationRules {
        rule {
            limit {
                minimum = 0.5
            }
        }
       includes [com.company.module1.*]
}`
```